# Loading remote files via PreloadJS in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, preloadjs

I have problem with the following snippet of code

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.05.21.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function load() {
       var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
 queue.on("error", handleComplete, this);
 queue.loadFile({id:"sound", src:"https://path-to-audio.mp3"});

 function handleComplete(e) {
    var t = 0;
 }
 }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="load();" class="load-image">Load</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

It doesnt work in IE9.I think its related to XMLHttpRequest problem in IE9. 
How to set up PreloadJS to fix this?

Thanks.